# Android JsonArrayRequest using Volley using WordPress 4.7

Tags: php, android, wordpress, rest

I have an Android app that reads the blog content from a WordPress site using the WordPress WP Rest API - my app was working fine tills, I upgraded WordPress to version 4.7.

The issue occurs in the JsonArrayRequest - it returns null - when I do a test using the Advanced Rest Client - i get a 400: Bad Request - I think the request sent from my Android App has the method post. When I test in the Advanced Rest Client method post gives me a 400: Bad Request and method Get gives me 200 and a json string with all the data.

Here is my code:

```
public void loadCategoriesData(){
    // Categories request to get list of featured categories
    String url = Constant.getURLBlogCategories();

    // Preparing volley's json object request
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
enter code here
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<Category>();

            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    JSONObject catObj = (JSONObject) response.get(i);
                    // category id
                    String catID = catObj.getString(TAG_TERM_ID);

                    // category name
                    String catTitle = catObj.getString(TAG_TERM_NAME);

                    Category category = new Category();
                    category.setId(catID);
                    category.setTitle(catTitle);

                    // add category to list
                    categories.add(category);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            // Store categories in shared pref
            AppController.getInstance().getPrefManger().storeCategories(categories);

            // String the main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // closing splash activity
            finish();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "System Error: " + error.getMessage());
            // show error toast
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "System Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            // closing splash activity
            finish();
        }
    }) {
```

I changed the line for jsonrequest to add method GET

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
```

It still did not work, same results. Do anyone has experience in how, I check what request method was used to send the request from my Android App?

Here is the url used for the request - 
    https://torbjornzetterlund.com/wp-json/wp/v2/categories?per_page=10

I use the following code to build the url

```
public static String getURLBlogCategories(){
    Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    String URL;
    builder.scheme("https").authority(IP_ADDRESS)
            .appendPath("wp-json")
            .appendPath("wp")
            .appendPath("v2")
            .appendPath("categories")
            .appendQueryParameter("per_page", String.valueOf(Per_Page));
    URL = builder.build().toString();
    Log.e("URL", URL);
    return URL;
}
```

thanks